# browser configuration

Tags: help

Recieved this notice when trying to browse for the first time time.

"Your IP address appears to be: 109.163.234.8

However, it does not appear to be Tor Browser.
Click here to go to the download page"

The notice says the browser is configured but does not appear to be a Tor Browser.  Q: what do I do next?

Comment: Download Tor for your OS on the torproject.org GitHub page on https://github.com/TheTorProject/gettorbrowser, basically, just download it as a zip, extract it in a new folder and click on the .exe (if your on Windows...). You can even copy the folder to an USB stick and use it from there.

Comment: Are you using Tor Browser?

Comment: Which site showed you this information?